# Invalid hook call with react-select implementation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-select

I am trying to use react-select in my code, but I keep getting this error:

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
```

What should I do? Here is the link to react select https://react-select.com/home#animated-components

```
import Select from 'react-select';

const options = [

  { value: '1', label: '1' },
  { value: '2', label: '2' },
  { value: '3', label: '3' },
  { value: '4', label: '4' },
  { value: '5', label: '5' },
  { value: '6', label: '6' },
  { value: '7', label: '7' },
  { value: '8', label: '8' },
  { value: '9', label: '9' },
]


function Sound() {
  return (
    <div className="Sound">
      <Select options={options} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Sound;
```

Comment: Can you please share your code it's not problem here

Comment: You are using hook wrong in some other part of the code

Comment: You may use a React hook inside any function. You have to use the hooks at the top level of the component funciton.

Answer (score 1):

Your Code looks perfect. Just need to check if you have installed `react-select`?

You can simply use this to install React Select `npm i --save react-select`.

This is checked locally. Working perfect.

Comment: good call.  Frustrating error for having run `npm` in the wrong directory...

Answer (score 0):

If what you shared is the whole code then it's probably because you are not importing react. Thus it thinks it is a javascript function which will not accept hooks.

Comment: If the author uses the 17 version it doesn't need to import React.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a little late but on my end the source of the bug is I did npm install one directory level up from the project, just entered the project directory and did an `npm install react-select` and also removed the package.json and node modules created in the project parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

Late on this, but i was getting this error due to trying to install in the wrong directory, not the react project directory. I was working with django and i was downloading on this folder instead

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).